# Firebase - efficiency of reading and fetching data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm a little bit worried about my approach on using Firebase, since I'm new to the whole topic.

Technically I don't even need a database connection. Everything is saved locally on the phone and nothing has to be fetched realtime.

The only function I wanna provide is for the user to create an account to be able to continuously save his input data to the database and later in case of changing device to fetch this data.

To implement this function, I create a user profile inside of the database for every user that signs up. Every time he adds data, the previously created profile is being updated. No fetching so far. In case of logging out, the user's data is being deleted from the phone - since it's possible that somebody else would use the phone. The only time that fetching happens is on log in. 
When the user has successfully logged in, the profiles data is being fetched from the database and allocated to the local properties.

**Is this a common approach? In case it's bad efficiency wise  - I'm open to any suggestion or other approach!**

Comment: You need an external database to store data outside of local persistance. Therefore.. Firebase is perfectly okay for what you are doing.

Comment: Your question states *Technically I don't even need a database connection.* but then says *continuously save his input data to the database and later in case of changing device to fetch this data* and also states that *fetched from the database and allocated to the local properties* which means you need to access the same data from two different devices and would need to fetch the data using a database connection. So... the question has conflicting data and is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem with this approach at all , some developers store large static data in firebase and cache them to avoid the pricing headache of continuously fetching them with every app open , regarding your approach the only thing is that singing in with providers like facebook/google+ may have some miss-synchronized data  the logged in user may change his name/profile while open your app and find them old ( this if you have social login in your app ) so you may reload them if this makes sense to your app in each open

Plus the user may login 2 devices at the same time so if you have any realtime update it will fail in the old login until the user logouts and logins again